# What are the names of the Kalpas as mentioned in Srimad Bhagavat Mahapurana or in any other scriptures?

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhagavata-purana, cosmology

Kalpa is a period of time as per Hindu scriptures - each Brahma Rules over various Kalpas, each Kalpa consisting of 14 Manvantaras.

Can I have the names of all the Kalpas?

NOTE: I want the names of the Kalpas from any authentic source like Puranas or Shrutis or any other scripture is fine - **answer not needed if the Purana referenced is Bhavishya Purana**

Comment: You want only mentioned in Bhagavatam or any other scripture will be fine?

Comment: There is no such a thing as "each Brahma", because there is only one Brahma!

Comment: Name of kalpas meaning? coz 1 kalpa is a day and 1 kalpa is a night of Lord Brahma. The day of Brahma is 2Kalpas.

Comment: The name of the Kalpas from any authentic source Puranas or Shrutis or any other scripture is fine - answer not needed if the Purana referenced is Bhavishya Purana.

Comment: There is only one Brahma for each era comprising of Brahma's life of one hundred years. At the end of his life Brahma, born in Padma Kalpa goes back into the navel of he Supreme Being and when a new era commences, Brahma is born anew.  As per Srimad Bhagavatam Third Canto Chapter XI verse 33:  "यदर्धमायुषस्तस्य परार्धमभिधीयते | पूर्वः परार्धोsपक्रान्तो ह्यपरोsद्य प्रवर्तते " Half the life time of Brahma is referred to as paraardha and till now, the first paraardha has passed and the second paraardha is now running.  Hence Brahma like any other Deva is mortal - only Sankara Narayana is immortal

Comment: The first Kalpa the day our Brahma was created is Padma Kalpa.  Passing through various Kalpas, Brahma will rule for one hundred years.  As of now the first paraardha (half) of Brahma's life is over and we are now running the second Paraardha or the 51st year.  Our present Kalpa is named Shweta Varaha Kalpa - or the Kalpa of the White Boar. I want to know the name of the Kalpas passed and still to come.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are thirty Kalpa are described by Lord Matsya in [Matsya Purana, Chapter 290](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-290). Their name are as follows:

> मत्स्य उवाच
> कल्पानां कीर्तनं वक्ष्ये महापातकनाशनम्। 
> यस्यानुकीर्तनादेव वेदपुण्येन युज्यते॥२॥
> प्रथमंश्वेतकल्पस्तु द्वितीयो नीललोहितः। 
> त्वामदेवास्तृतीयस्तु ततो राथन्तरोऽपरः॥ ३॥ 
> रौरवः पञ्चमः प्रोक्तः षष्ठो इति स्मृतः। 
> ससेमार्थं बृहत्कल्पः कन्दर्पोऽष्टम उच्यते॥४॥ 
> सद्योऽथ नवमः प्रोक्त ईशानो दशमः स्मृतः॥ 
> तम एकादशः प्रोक्तस्तथा सारस्वतः परः॥५॥ 
> त्रयोदश उदानस्तु गारुडोऽथ चतुर्दशः। 
> कौर्मः पञ्चदशः प्रोक्तः पौर्णमास्यामजायत॥६॥
> षोडशो नारसिंहस्तु समानस्तु ततोऽपरः। 
> अाग्नेयोऽष्टादशः प्रोक्तः सोमकल्पस्तथापरः॥७॥ 
> मानवो विंशतिः प्रोक्तस्तत्पुमानिति चापरः। 
> वैकुण्ठश्वापरस्तद्वल्लक्ष्मीकिलप्लस्तथापर:॥८॥ 
> चतुर्विशतिमः प्रोक्तः सावित्रीकल्पसंज्ञकः। 
> पञ्चर्विशस्ततो घोरो वाराहस्तु ततोऽपरः॥९॥ 
> सतविंशोऽथ वैराजो गौरीकल्पस्तथा।पर:। 
> माहेश्वरस्तु स प्रोक्तस्त्रिपुरं यत्र घातितम्॥ १०॥ 
> पितृकल्पस्तशास्ले तु या कुहू ब्रह्मणः पुरा। 
> इत्येवं ब्रह्मणो मासः सर्वपातकनाशनः॥ ११॥

> Lord Matsya said- "I shall narrate the description of the Kalpas, the dispeller of all sins. Even by reciting the names of Kalpas, one gets the merit of the study of Vedas. They are
> (1) Šveta, 
> (2) Nīlalohita, 
> (3) Vāmadeva, 
> (4) Rāthantrara, 
> (5) Raurava, 
> (6) Deva, 
> (7) Brhat, 
> (8) Kandarpa, 
> (9) Sadya, 
> (10) Iśāna, 
> (11) Tama, 
> (12) Sārasvata, 
> (13) Udāna, 
> (14) Gāruda, 
> (15) Kaurma, 
> (16) Nārasirinha, 
> (17) Samāna, 
> (18) Ägneya, 
> (19) Soma, 
> (20) Mānava, 
> (21) Tatpumān, 
> (22) Vaikuņtha, 
> (23) Laksmī, 
> (24) Sāvitrī, 
> (25) Ghora, 
> (26) Vārāha, 
> (27) Vairāja, 
> (28) Gauri, 
> (29) Mahesvara, in course of which Tripura was killed, 
> (30) Pitty, at the end of which occurs Lord Brahma's Kuhl. 
> These Kalpas form one month of 30 days of Brahma, each Kalpa forming a day; and one who hears them is freed from all sins.'

Answer (score 8):

The **Vayu Purana Chapter 21** also gives the names of Kalpas but they're all different from the ones in Matsya Puran. Also this text mentions 34 Kalpas, 4 more than those in Matsya Puran and I am sharing the whole lot:

[image]