# How many Kalpas are there in total?

Tags: time, kalpa

How many Kalpas are there in total and do they occur again in cycle form?

Comment: Related [What are the names of the Kalpas as mentioned in Srimad Bhagavat Mahapurana or in any other scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20074/what-are-the-names-of-the-kalpas-as-mentioned-in-srimad-bhagavat-mahapurana-or-i)

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani not only related, but in fact a duplicate.

Comment: @Pratimaputra It looks like cyclic form is missing in that question.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani mentioning all kalpas in the sequential order means its repeated so far as i understood.

Comment: @Pratimaputra Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Due to cyclic nature, it's nearly impossible to calculate number of all the Kalpas of all Brahmas of all time. However, this can be be calculated for current Brahma.

Brahma's one day is equal to 1 Kalpa. Brahma's night also equal to 1 Kalpa but there would be no creation during that time.

The current Brahma has completed 50 years or one Pardha at the end of previous Padma kalpa. His 2nd Pardha started with current Sveta Varaha kalpa.

So, [(1+1)x360x50] = 36000 Kalpas have been passed in current Brahma's lifespan where 18000 were for his night (when no creation exists).

Comment: You should cite some sources. [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277) you can find many useful resources.